# .Net Core JsonConfigSource could not find the existing file

Tags: c#, configuration, io, .net-core

[image]

I think this picture just get everything clear. Why? The file just exists there! Why I got the FileNotFoundException?

Totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

This error is sent too when the user has no permissions in the folder. I would check the permissions of the user running the application in this folder.

Comment: Thanks, it's a clue. I'll have a try.

Comment: Not work for me. After setting dotnet.exe and visual studio to run as administrator, I still get this error.